# Is it possible to nest `at` with setters?

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

I'd like to set a value in 2 level map - i.e. to a key in a map which is a value for some key in an "outer" map. For ordinary Map I could use something like `m & at 42 ?= "value"`
But I could not find any way to nest 2 `at`'s
What is the easiest way to set such nested value using lens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

User trapdoor showed up that there is a nicer solution - http://juick.com/qrilka/2602819#19 and it is right in the lens library : [non](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-3.10/docs/Control-Lens-Iso.html#g:5)

Answer (score 2):

Kind of, we can use the `_Just` prism which will no-op if there is no key available. This has the unfortunate effect that we can't create keys 2 layers down. But as an example

```
at2 :: Ord k => k -> k -> IndexedTraversal' k (Map k (Map k v)) (Maybe v)
at2 k1 k2 = at k1 . _Just . at k2
```

Comment: Maybe it's possible to use `maybe` (or its lens analog)? At the moment it seems like explicit creation of new "submap" should look a little bit better